# How to databinding between custom component in AIR application?

Tags: php, apache-flex, air, flash

In my Main application I used label `(like id=firstname)` so we can use in main used firstname.text for databinding.  But I have created canves custom component and load in main application using viewstack.
In canves custom component how can I Bind  label(id=firstname).

I tried:
`var username:string = firstname.text` but not show undefine firstname.
How can I access all label and component in Main application to custom application.  Please refer any URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, you use [binding](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/quickstart/using_data_binding/). Add a property called `firstname` to CustomComponent.mxml and bind it to your `firstnameTextbox`:

```
<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        private var _firstname : String;

        [Bindable] // only required on getter
        public function get firstname() : String
        {
            return _firstname;
        }

        public function set firstname(value : String) : void
        {
            _firstname = value;
        }
    ]]>
</mx:Script>
<mx:Textbox id="firstnameTextBox" text="{firstname}" />
```

Then, you bind the `firstname` to a value in your main.mxml:

```
<mx:Application>
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            [Bindable]
            private var _firstname : String;
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>
    <cs:CustomComponent id="customComponent" firstname="{_firstname}" />
</mx:Application>
```

Now, whenever you change `_firstname` in Main.mxml, it will automatically filter up to the textbox in your custom component.

Comment: thanks Richard Szalay . But show Data binding will not be able to detect assignments to "_firstname"

Comment: [Bindable] actually causes the compiler to generate wrapping code around the member so it will still be able to detect assignments.